# Edit CV tag editor alignment issue

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, tags, jobs, design

I see an alignment issue in the [edit cv](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv/get-started)'s tag editor section.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: padding bottom is missing]

Some CSS class is overridden after the page load, GIF image for while refresh the page:

> [image: Page refresh in edit CV]

Google chrome Version `47.0.2526.106 dev-m`

Comment: +1 for animated bug report